# Why is this gradle flatDir example failing?

Tags: gradle

I'm completely new to gradle. I've put the following build.gradle together as a means of seeing how dependencies get pulled from a flatDir repository. The 'localrepo' directory contains two files 'a.txt', and 'b.txt' and nothing else. When I run 'gradle dependencies' I get failures:

```
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

copytest
+--- :a.txt: FAILED
\--- :b.txt: FAILED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 5.506 secs
```

Why?

Here's my build.gradle:

```
configurations {
  copytest
}

repositories {
  flatDir name: 'localRepository', dirs: 'localrepo'
}

dependencies {
  copytest ':a.txt'
  copytest ':b.txt'
}

task copyTask(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.copytest
  into 'result'
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A `flatDir` repo uses a simple heuristic to turn the dependency's module name into the filename to be searched for. If you specify `:a.txt`, Gradle will search for `a.txt.jar`, or, if you have `project.version` set, also for `a.txt-theVersion.jar`. To add arbitrary files to a configuration, instead of declaring a `flatDir` repo, you can use `copytest files("some/path")`.

Comment: Thanks. The point of the exercise is to learn how to use repositories for non-jar files. I need to ultimately setup an Artifactory containing lots of binaries that have nothing to do with Java at all (images, .pdf files, etc.) It's my understanding that repositories can  "hold anything". So, with that said, how do I access my simplistic example of pulling out two .txt files?

(As an aside, if I rename the files to 'a.jar' and 'b.jar', it still fails.)

Comment: If you want to prepare for using Artifactory, you need to declare a `maven` or `ivy` repository, not a `flatDir` repository. You could use a `file:` repository URL, but I'd probably go with a local Artifactory installation. To answer your second question, you'd have to rename the file to `a.txt.jar`. Maybe `:a:1.0@txt` would match `a.txt` (or `a-1.0.txt`), but I'm not sure, as `flatDir` repos are special and limited.

Comment: :a:1.0@txt did the trick, Peter. Thank you. Now that I have my contrived test completed, I can start evolving things into using Artifactory.